# ASP.NET MVC : Get text Box input in a controller action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 2 two textboxes in a page and a button. now when the user clicks the button I want to pass the text entered by the user in the action method of a controller. this might be silly. but I am new to MVC. pls tell me how to do this. Here is the code that I have tried.

**View**

```
<input type="text" name="input_domain_id" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Domain ID" autofocus required>
            <input type="password" name="input_domain_password" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Domain Password" required>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <p><button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("VerifyLogin", "LdapLoginVerify")'">Login</button></p>
            </div>
```

and In the controller

```
 public ActionResult VerifyLogin(string input_domain_id, string input_domain_password)
        {
    return(view);
}
```

In my code I am getting null values In both the parameters.
Pls tell me how to do this.p

Comment: Before you go much further, go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to understand how MVC works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need HTML for the form. The best way to do this is to use the MVC helper:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="text" name="input_domain_id" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Domain ID" autofocus required>
    <input type="password" name="input_domain_password" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Domain Password" required>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <p><button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("VerifyLogin", "LdapLoginVerify")'">Login</button></p>
    </div>
}
```

You most likely will also want to make sure you have two actions.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult VerifyLogin()
{
    return View(/* optional model with prepopulated data */);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult VerifyLogin(string input_domain_id, string input_domain_password)
{
    // Do stuff with posted values...

    return View();
}
```

You should also look into using helpers for you inputs, buttons, etc...

@Html.EditorFor(), @Html.PasswqordFor, etc.

Comment: Note: the `onclick="location....` needs to be removed from the submit button

Comment: @StephenMuecke if i don't call the action method in the onclick event then how that action method is going to be called?

Comment: Its a submit button, which automatically submits the values in the form to the action specified in the forms `action` parameter. All your `onclick` event is doing is making a GET call without even passing any parameters (so of course they were null). Learn MVC. Do not hard code your html, html use helpers to bind to model properties. Post back a model, not individual parameters etc. etc.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you. your comment helped to clear my concepts.  i will surely now read the mvc tutorials first